# Master Page Converted From an HTML Page Doesn't Have an .aspx File, Instead Has a .master File

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, aspx

I have created a SharePoint Master page by converting an HTML File. The conversion was successful. After the conversion there should be 1 pair of files with .html & .aspx extensions.

Unfortunately after the conversion I got an .html file and a .master file.

I found this issue when I tried to add a SharePoint Search Box Web Part using SharePoint Designer 2013 to the custom master page and also I got the below message too.

#### The message's screenshot

[image: The message's screenshot]

Comment: Isn't the expected behavior to get a .master file? .aspx files are used for page layouts and other pages, not master pages. See for example here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/sharepoint-2013-design-manager-html-to-master-page-convers/

Comment: OK I accept that. But I want to add web part to the Custom MasterPage. Exactly the 'Search Box' web part. How can I get that done? When I tried to add that and I got the above mentioned message.

Comment: Do you want to add your custom webpart on the master page or existing SharePoint webpart on it?

Comment: I want to add one of SharePoint WebParts to the MasterPage

Comment: Add that webpart in any of the page, Open SharePoint designer & copy the XML code of that webpart. Go to your page layout & edit it in designer & paste that code.

Comment: My purpose of adding this webpart to the Master Page is that in every page the web part will be visible and accessible. So how am I suppose to solve that issue then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I just have to add the webpart using the 'Design manager's', 'Edit Master Pages' option.

Thanks for your help!

Chiranthaka